# MYSQL choosing continuous record has conditions

Tags: mysql

For instance

```
No          Condition
1               NULL
2               O
3               NULL
4               NULL
5               NULL
6               NULL
7               NULL
8               O
9               NULL
10             NULL
11             NULL
12             O
```

What is the SQL for wanting to select the No with NULL Condition and it's following two records also have NULL Condition?

For this table, 3, 4 , 5 and 9 should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `no` is consecutive with no gaps -- as in your sample data -- then you can use `join`:

```
select t.no
from t join
     t1
     on t1.no = t.no + 1 join
     t2
     on t2.no = t.no + 2
where t.condition is null and
      t1.condition is null and
      t2.condition is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `No` field has no gaps (as indicated in the question), self join your table 3 times on increasing `No` values and select the records where all `Condition` fields are null:

```
select t1.No
from yourtable t1
inner join yourtable t2 on t1.No+1=t2.No
inner join yourtable t3 on t1.No+2=t3.No
where t1.Condition is null and t2.Condition is null and t3.Condition is null
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use correlated subqueries to retrieve the value of the condition column of the next two rows. For example:

```
 SELECT t1.no
   FROM mytable t1
  WHERE t1.condition IS NULL
    AND ( SELECT (t2.condition IS NULL)
            FROM mytable t2
           WHERE t2.no > t1.no 
           ORDER BY t2.no
           LIMIT 0,1
        )
    AND ( SELECT (t3.condition IS NULL)
            FROM mytable t3
           WHERE t3.no > t1.no 
           ORDER BY t3.no
           LIMIT 1,1
        )
 ORDER BY t1.no
```

This won't necessarily give the best performance. But this is valid MySQL syntax, and it does return the specified result set.

This assumes that if there is a gap in the No column, the intent is to check the next two rows with higher values of `No`. If the specification is to check only rows `No+1` and `No+2`, then the `> t1.no` can be replaced with `= t1.no + 1` and `= t1.no + 2`, and replace `LIMIT 1,1` with`LIMIT 0,1`.